# Cannot set property 'helloMessage' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I get the error following error

> Cannot set property 'helloMessage' of undefined

when I run the following code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/helloWorld.js"></script>
    <h1 ng-controller="HelloWorldCtrl">{{helloMessage}}</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Javascript (helloWorld.js):

```
(function (angular) {

    function HelloWorldCtrl ($scope) {
        $scope.helloMessage = "Hello World";
    }

    angular.module("app", []).controller("HelloWorldCtrl", ["$scope", HelloWorldCtrl()]);

})(angular);
```

Any ideas?  I am using angular version 1.2.28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not invoke the controller constructor function, instead just provide the controller function reference. When you invoke it manually 1) You are invoking it right away and setting undefined (return value) as the controller, if at all invocation succeeds(It fails right there in your case). 2) There is no dependency injected due to manual invocation which otherwise will be injected by angular DI engine($injector)

Change

```
.controller("HelloWorldCtrl", ["$scope", HelloWorldCtrl()]);
                                                        ^___
```

to

```
.controller("HelloWorldCtrl", ["$scope", HelloWorldCtrl]);
```